# How to know how many tabs are open in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a task where I have to take a look at 211 ruby files. I need to know how many tabs are open. Is there any way I can get some statusbar or something similar that can tell me how many tabs are open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has a a built-in help functionality:

```
:help tabpagenr()
:help 'ruler'
:help 'statusline'
```

In order to display the number of tab pages in your status line, you may want to add `%{tabpagenr('$')}` to your `statusline` or `rulerformat` options. For example,

```
:set ruler
:let &rulerformat='%39(%-6{strpart(&ft,0,5)}%5.5b%6.6(<%B>%) %5.5l,%-7.7(%.3c%.4V%) %6{tabpagenr(''$'')}T%)'
```

On the other hand, the Vim I am running won't let me open more than 10 tabs at the same time...

Comment: can you explain a bit more. i am a new vim user and you can guess what stage i am in :)

Comment: @BishishtBhatta: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks bro. Also how can i put these into the vimrc?

Comment: @BishishtBhatta: Of course. Not need for the leading `:` in `.vimrc`.